# Java client aborts on SNI unrecognized_name warning

Tags: sni

I am trying to connect the domain **platform.modsolar.net** using socket. But I am getting

> javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert: 
>   unrecognized_name

I am using Java 7.
[The host name(platform.modsolar.net) is correctly listed in the SANs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djGi5.png)

What am I missing here ?